# How can I dynamically modify the text of the Global: result summary?

Tags: views, 8

I'm using the Views module to displays search result. In the header of the views, I added the `Global: Result summary` to show result summary.

```
 "@total Results (@per_page per page)"  //Output: 25 Results (20 per page)
```

[image]

But depending on search result count the **Global: Result summary text should change. Meaning I want to dynamically change the text based on the search result count. For example, if total search result count is less than 10(configured Items to display)), then result summary text should be displayed like below.

```
 "@total Results"
  Output: 5 Results
```

How can I achieve that that?

Comment: The problem is that [views is not accepting twig in global result](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2888320), else it would be easy to answer. I think the only option is to define your own [Views area handler plugin](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21area%21AreaPluginBase.php/group/views_area_handlers/8.2.x), maybe inspired from the one you are refering [Drupal\views\Plugin\views\area\Result](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21area%21Result.php/class/Result/8.2.x).